# When is an element actually added to DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, dom

Let´s say I have following code snippet:

```
var NewNode = document.createElement("div");

NewNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello World!"));

document.body.appendChild(NewNode);
```

At what lines do I actually append an element to the DOM tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question very specifically, you're appending to the document DOM tree in line three. But there's a conceptual confusion in the wording of your question.

There's more than one DOM tree after the first line. There's (1) the DOM tree of the document, which you are referring to as "the" DOM tree, although that's not strictly speaking the only one, and there's (2) a DOM tree consisting of a single `div` element. At this point, these two DOM trees are not connected. After the execution of line two, the newer DOM tree has two nodes in it, not just one. And to be perfectly persnickety, immediately after `createTextNode` returns but before `appendChild` is called, there are three DOM trees. After the third line, you're back to a single DOM tree, the one accessible through `document`.

Answer (score 3):

Here NewNode is being added to DOM:

```
document.body.appendChild(NewNode);
```

Here you just create an object in memory:

```
var NewNode = document.createElement("div");

NewNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello World!"));
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to know. I heard that DOM manipulation can be very costly. So adding lots and lots of elements to `NewNode` **before** appending it to the `body` does not hurt, right?

Comment: In modern browsers, DOM manipulation performance is actually pretty hard to improve in this way. It used to be that building things up in memory and then adding them to the DOM at the last minute would improve performance, but modern Chrome and Firefox (at least) will delay document reflows as long as possible (which is the costly part), so it doesn't tend to matter. Still, you can get serious performance gains in IE8. If you care about IE8 performance, you may also want to look into `DocumentFragment`.

Comment: @Amberlamps: creating new DOM nodes the way you do can be costly, but the easiest fix is the way jQuery deals with things: `renderer = document.createElement('div'); renderer.innerHTML = '<a>String</a><br/><p>With lots of elements</p>';` This will call the browsers rendering engine to load the string as HTML, without having to call the `HTMLElement` constructor over and over again. Remember that the DOM isn't _"native"_ to JS, it's just an API...

Answer (score 1):

The last line: `document.body.appendChild(NewNode);` adds the elements to the current rendered DOM. There is, however nothing to stop you from building several separate dom trees: you can parse x/html documents into a DOM tree, or create a bunch of new elements and build a new tree/DOM fragment.